# Child theme does not load menu or parent theme components

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, parent-child-theme

i'm using magento 2.1.6.

I'm using the theme everything and I want to extend one of their child themes into a new child theme. I am using these files and this structure:

folder:

> app/design/frontend/MyCompany/newstylechild/

**folders:**

> Magento_Theme > layout > default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.svg</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> media > preview.jpg
>
> web > css > source > variables > _body.less
>
> web > images > logo.svg
>
> web > js

files in themechild:
**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/MyCompany/newstylechild', __DIR__
);
```

**theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>NewStyle Child</title>
<parent>Emthemes/everything_newstyle</parent>
<media>
<preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media>
</theme>
```

========================

After changes, i run this commands:

> rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/*
>   var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex php
>
> bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

After this, i apply in CONTENT > design (configuration), like this image:
[image]

But in the frontend, just appears this:
[image]

I think some configuration is missing, as it does not load some tabs in STORES> configuration (design) (image here)
[image]

what can I do? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check in theme.xml whether you have specified parent theme correctly

path: app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme/theme.xml

```
<title>New theme</title>

<parent>Magento/luma</parent>

<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
</media>
```

Comment: yes, i have. Because the deploy cant run without a correctly path ....